# How to reverse a dictionary that has repeated values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with almost 100,000 (key, value) pairs and the majority of the keys map to the same values. For example:

```
mydict =  {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 2, 'd': 3, 'h': 1, 'j': 3}
```

What I want to do, is to reverse the dictionary so that each value in `mydict` is going to be a key at the `reverse_dict` and is going to map to a list of all the `mydict.keys()` that used to map to that value in `mydict`. So based on the example above I would get:

```
reversed_dict = {1: ['a', 'b', 'h'], 2: ['c', 'e'] , 3: ['d', 'j']}
```

I came up with a solution that is very expensive and I want to hear any ideas for doing this more efficiently than this:

```
reversed_dict = {}
for value in mydict.values():
    reversed_dict[value] = []
    for key in mydict.keys():
        if mydict[key] == value:
            if key not in reversed_dict[value]: 
                reversed_dict[value].append(key)
```

Comment: Notice the question is distinct in that non-unique values need to be handled properly, without overwriting them once they become new keys (by using a list).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

reversed_dict = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in mydict.items():
    reversed_dict[value].append(key)
```

Comment: You may want to use `defaultdict(set)` and replace `append()` with `add()`. This would remove duplicates, but keep uniq values.

Comment: `defaultdict(list)` - nice!

Comment: Note that while it works like charm, this also changes type from `dict` to `defaultdict`, so to get a standard Python dictionary object one needs to cast it back to it (e.g. with `dict(reversed_dict)`).

Answer (score 5):

```
reversed_dict = {}
for key, value in mydict.items():
    reversed_dict.setdefault(value, [])
    reversed_dict[value].append(key)
```

Comment: You can even do both operations on one line: `reversed_dict.setdefault(value, []).append(key)`

Answer (score 1):

```
for k,v in dict.iteritems():
    try:
      reversed_dict[v].append(k)
    except KeyError:
       reversed_dict[v]=[k]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're wasting a few cycles by replacing a key with the same key again and again...

```
reversed_dict = {}
for value in mydict.values():
    if value not in reversed_dict.keys(): #checking to be sure it hasn't been done.
        reversed_dict[value] = []
        for key in mydict.keys():
            if mydict[key] == value:
                if key not in reversed_dict[value]: reversed_dict[value].append(key)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

snd = itemgetter(1)

def sort_and_group(itr, f):
    return groupby(sorted(itr, key=f), f)

mydict =  {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'e': 2, 'd': 3, 'h': 1, 'j': 3}
reversed_dict = {number: [char for char,_ in v] 
                 for number, v in sort_and_group(mydict.items(), snd)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reversed_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key, value in dict_.iteritems():
  reversed_dict[value].append(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse_dict(mydict):
    v={}
    for x,y in mydict.items():
        if  y not in v:
            v[y]=[x]
        else:
            v[y].append(x)
    return v

print(reverse_dict(mydict))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This looks like a rehash of a couple of existing answers. Please read [answer] and avoid repeating answers, especially on old questions (this one is over eleven years old).