# Getting "TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable" when trying to reverse dictionary with non-unique values

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to reverse the dictionary with non-unique values. I am getting error:

> TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

```
my_dict1={"House": "A", "Apartment": "A", "Condo": "B"}
my_dict2={}
for k,v in my_dict1.items:
    my_dict2[v]= my_dict2.get(v,[])
    my_dict2[v].append(k)

print my_dict2
```

Desired output: `{'A':['House','Apartment'],'B':['Condo']}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as typo. Otherwise, it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823315/how-to-reverse-a-dictionary-that-has-repeated-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing `()` on `items`:

```
In [78]:

my_dict1={"House": "A", "Apartment": "A", "Condo": "B"}
my_dict2={}
for k,v in my_dict1.items(): #<- missing ()
    my_dict2[v]= my_dict2.get(v,[])
    my_dict2[v].append(k)
my_dict2
Out[78]:
{'B': ['Condo'], 'A': ['Apartment', 'House']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Call the function `my_dict1.items()`. You are just having a function object there and hence the error. That is the line

```
for k,v in my_dict1.items:
```

should be:

```
for k,v in my_dict1.items():
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add parens to call the method.

Also, you can use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_dict2 = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in my_dict1.iteritems():
    my_dict2[v].append(k)

print my_dict2
# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': ['House', 'Apartment'], 'B': ['Condo']})
```

Also for python2 you should use `iteritems()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following one-liner:

```
{v: [k for k, v2 in a.items() if v2 == v] for v in set(a.values())}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way to do it.

This function uses the `setdefault` method of a dictionary, so that it creates a key if it is not defined yet.

```
def invert(d):
    res = {}
    {res.setdefault(v, []).append(k) for k, v in d.items()}
    return res
```